# Dúvida no caso de Paragem

Tags: haskell

```
listasIguais :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool

listasIguais [] p = False

listasIguais p [] = False

listasIguais (x: xs) (y:ys) = x == y && (listasIguais xs ys)

listasIguais [(2,4),(4,6),(8,9)] [(1,4),(2,6),(4,9)]
False
```

Este resultado deveria de ser verdadeiro. Penso que me enganei no caso de paragem. Será que me sabem dizer qual é o meu erro ?

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi bem, você está querendo dizer que as listas são iguais caso o segundo elemento de cada item seja igual. Ou seja, a comparação deveria ser feita apenas pelo segundo elemento da tupla.

Na verdade, o código atual está comparando tuplas e não apenas o segundo elemento. Como a tupla `(2, 4)` é diferente de `(1, 4)` a comparação já falha aí.

Para comparar pelo segundo elemento pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```haskell
module Main where

listasIguais :: (Eq b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)] -> Bool
listasIguais [] [] = True
listasIguais [] p = False
listasIguais p [] = False
listasIguais (x:xs) (y:ys) = (snd x) == (snd y) && (listasIguais xs ys)

emptyList = []::[(Int, Int)]

main = do
    print $ listasIguais emptyList emptyList -- True
    print $ listasIguais [] [(1,4),(2,6),(4,9)] -- False
    print $ listasIguais [(2,4),(4,6),(8,9)] [(1,4),(2,6),(4,9)] -- True
```

Repare que foi necessário mudar a declaração de `listasIguais` para assumir que é uma lista de tuplas.

Repare também o uso de `snd` para pegar o segundo elemento de cada tupla.

A declaração de `emptyList` é necessária para ajudar o compilador a entender o tipo quando a lista está vazia.

E faltava incluir o caso de duas listas vazias. Sem essa equação, a função sempre retornaria `False` pois no final ía cair em uma das duas equações de lista vazia que retornam `False`.

Comment: Obrigado, fiquei esclarecido 

Comment: Não esquece de votar e marcar a resposta como escolhida :)